# Brightness control is blocked after reaching minimum

Tags: screen, brightness, backlight

Several days ago I tried to fix a quite popular problem. I have Ubuntu 15.10. In my computer the brightness control keys weren't working.

I have added a file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
with following content:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "card0"
Driver "intel"
Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Now I can adjust the brightness, but every time when I reach the lowest brighness possible - it gets blocked and I cannot return to a higher level of brightness.
Have you encountered a similar problem? My computer is Samsung NP-R509.

```
    xxx@xxx-R509:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4     Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c042
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: This is a good question. I do not have this problem. This must be related to the device. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

So what you have done is obviously one of the most common solutions but people have reported they had to perform the following extra step as well:

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Change this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"`
3. save and exit.
4. run `sudo update-grub`
5. reboot

I know this is usually done when brightness settings are not working at all but I guess there's no harm in trying it out.

Comment: After implementing your advice nothing has changed. When the brightness reaches minimum I still cannot increase it.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, will dig some more and update if I find something.

Comment: +50 Because you tried to find  a solution.